# Height of $I$ = Height of $I K[X]$

Tags: commutative-algebra

In the proof of Theorem 23 in Matsumura's *Commutative Algebra* on page 85, he wrote

> Since $A$ is a subring of $B = A[X]/I$, we have $A \cap I = (0)$. Therefore, if $K$ denotes the quotient field of $A$ then $\text{ht}(I) = \text{ht}(IK[X]) \leq \dim K[X] = 1$.

I have trouble seeing why this is true. In the context of the theorem: $A$ is a noetherian domain and $I$ is an ideal of $A[X]$ such that $I \cap A = (0)$. How can one prove that $\text{ht}(I) = \text{ht}(IK[X])$ where $K$ is quotient field of $A$? (Assume that $I$ is prime if one must.)

I have experimented this with $A = \mathbb{Z}$. Dimension theory says that $\dim A[X] = 2$ so $\text{ht}(I) \in \{0, 1, 2\}$. If $\text{ht}(I) = 2$ then (assuming that $I$ is prime) we must have some prime chain $I = P_0 \supsetneq P_1 \supsetneq (0)$ so $I$ is maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ (otherwise, $\dim \mathbb{Z}[X] > 2$. But from the knowledge of $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}[X])$ (cf. proposition on page 22 of M. Reid's *Undergraduate Commutative Algebra*), maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ are of form $(p, g)$ with $p$ prime, $g \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ such that $g \mod p$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$; hence some non-zero prime $p \in I$. If $\text{ht}(I) = 0$ then $I = (0)$ so obviously $\text{ht}(I) = \text{ht}(I \mathbb{Q}[X]) = 0$. The remaining case is when $\text{ht}(I) = 1$ i.e. $I = (f)$ with $f$ being an irreducible polynomial. Then $I K[X]$ is maximal ideal of $K[X]$ and we again have $\text{ht}(I) = \text{ht}(I \mathbb{Q}[X]) = 1$. I don't see how one generalizes from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you only need $\le$, and this holds in general.

We have the following setting:

> $I\subset R$ an ideal, and $S\subset R$ a multiplicative set with $S\cap I=\emptyset$. Then $\operatorname{ht}(I)\le\operatorname{ht}(S^{-1}I)$.

If $I$ is prime this is obvious from the correspondence of primes between $R$ and $S^{-1}R$.
Otherwise, $\operatorname{ht}(S^{-1}I)=\operatorname{ht}(S^{-1}P)$ for some prime $P$ such that $S^{-1}I\subset S^{-1}P$. Then $I\subset P$, so $\operatorname{ht}(I)\le\operatorname{ht}(P)$ and thus we get $\operatorname{ht}(I)\le\operatorname{ht}(S^{-1}I)$.

Note that if $I=P_1\cap P_2$ with $P_1,P_2$ incomparable prime ideals, and $S=R\setminus P_1$, then $\operatorname{ht}(I)=\min(\operatorname{ht}(P_1),\operatorname{ht}(P_2))$ while $S^{-1}I=S^{-1}P_1$, so $\operatorname{ht}(S^{-1}I)=\operatorname{ht}(P_1)$ which can be strictly greater than $\min(\operatorname{ht}(P_1),\operatorname{ht}(P_2))$.

Comment: In your case $R=A[X]$, and $S=A\setminus\{0\}$.